# Change functionality of menu key to recent apps

Tags: root-access, recents-screen

phone: Samsung Ace 3 (gt-s7272) android: 4.2.2 (rooted)

Is there anyway than I can remap the functionality of the capacitive keys of my phone? Currently one touch on menu key obviously will load the menu in the foreground app but I want to change it to launch recent apps(be default it is done with holding the physical home button) and if possible, for not losing the functionality of loading the context menu, holding the menu key itself launches the menu.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Xposed module [Xposed Additions](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) works with pretty much any ROM from Gingerbread up, and you can remap any physical button on the phone.

Comment: Just in case that the OP doesn't know what Xposed is: It's a framework that can change the behavoir of your phone. You can add some big features (like the above one), and do many useful stuff. You need to install Xposed framework before you can apply a Xposed module.